# How to chain multiple concurrent rx-java Single

Tags: java, rx-java2, vert.x

I'm learning Rx-Java2 with Vert.x and I would like to chain a success configuration retrieving with some parallel tasks.

I've created a method that search for the configuration and returns a Single subscribe to it and it worked fine.
But I'm in doubt where and how do call the subsequent tasks:

```
   public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
      Single<JsonObject> configSingle = prepareConfigurationAsync();
      configSingle.subscribe(onSuccess -> {
        System.out.println(onSuccess);
        -->   Single<Boolean> task1 = prepareLongAsyncTask1(onSuccess).subscribe(...); 
        -->   Completable task2 = prepareLongAsyncTask2(onSuccess)..subscribe(...); 

    }, onError -> {
        startFuture.fail(onError);
    }));
```

The way I did seems to be working, but without parallelism. how could I achieve it ?

How and where should I dispose those subscriptions ?

Comment: There is a section in the [Getting Started](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#dependend-sub-flows) about dependent flows and continuations; it may get you started and work things out from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing with some other source is usually done via `flatMap`. Doing things in parallel is often done with `zip` or `merge`. In your case, I don't think you need the value of the inner `Single` as part of the output so you can try this:

```java
 Completable config = prepareConfigurationAsync()
     .flatMapCompletable(success ->
         System.out.println(success);
         return Completable.mergeArray (
             prepareLongAsyncTask1(success)
                 .doOnSuccess(innerSuccess -> /* ... */)
                 .toCompletable(),
             prepareLongAsyncTask2(success)
                 .doOnComplete(() ->  /* ... */)
         )
      );

  config
  .subscribe( () -> /* completed */, error -> /* error'd */);
```

Comment: Wow, very interesting... 
Is the subscription of the inner tasks done 'automatically' by the operator merge?

Comment: Yes. Whenever you feel you want to subscribe to a source inside a `subscribe` or `doOnX` method, you need to think `merge`, `zip` or `flatMap` most of the time.

Comment: Hey akarnokd, what does the `.ignoreElement()` supposed to do? 

I'm getting a compilation error on it: `The method ignoreElement() is undefined for the type Single<Boolean>`.

When I removed it then I got a error in the `merge()` method. 

Do I need to convert the inner Single into Completable?

Comment: Right, it is called `toCompletable` in `Single`.

Comment: Yep, I needed to convert the single using `.toCompletable()` and use the `Completable.mergeArray` instead.